# How to set inital state as props in react with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set state as props in react using hooks and I'm getting error:
`Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
▶ 34 stack frames were collapsed.`

My code:
First Component :

```
const List = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([{}])
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await fetch(
                'http://localhost:5000/api',
            );
            const result = await data.json();
            setItems(result);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
   return (
          <ActualList items={items}/>
    )
}
```

and the second component:

```
const ActualList = props => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([{}])
    setItems(props.items)
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling setItem in every render. Each time you change a state value, your component will be re-rendered, which will cause another state change, another re-render....

You should conditionally call setItems

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass props to `useState`:

```
const ActualList = props => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(props.items) // pass props.items as an initial state
    }
```

Comment: I get an empty array

Answer (score 1):

So I eventually figured out how to do this, in case someone needs it here is the code :

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([{}]);
useEffect(() => setItems(props.items), [props])
```